# getting a list of changed files from git remote using isomorphic-git

Tags: git

I need to get a list of files that have changed on the github remote that are out of sync with the local.

From the command line I can achieve this with:

```
git fetch origin && git diff origin/master --name-only
```

And that works perfectly, but as there is no isomorphic-git.diff() function (https://github.com/isomorphic-git/isomorphic-git), how can I achieve the same list of differences using isomorphic-git as I do with the command line ?

```
var opts = {
  fs, 
  http, 
  dir, 
  url: url,
  
  onAuth(url) {
    //cl('Authenticating...',url);
    return {username: gitpat}
  },
  
  onAuthSuccess() {
    //cl('Authenticated');
  } 
} 

  // git fetch origin && git diff origin/master --name-only  
  git.fetch(Object.assign(opts,{
    singleBranch  : true,
    depth         : 1,
    remote        : 'origin'
  }))
    .catch(ce)
    .then(function(res){
      cl(res)  
    });
```

Comment: "as there in no git diff() isomorphic" is quite unclear. Could you reformulate / elaborate?

Comment: thanks, in the nodejs isomorphic-git module (https://github.com/isomorphic-git/isomorphic-git), there appears to be no function that is equivalent to the command line "git diff"